# How to remove related data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have an MVC Edit page, on which I also edit related data.

On postback, I have the following piece of code that handles my inserts, updates and deletes for related data:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    Guid myGuid = new Guid();

    //-- Set PK and FK values --
    foreach (AccountType_Organisatie myAccType_Org in myOrg.AccountType_Organisaties)
    {
        if (myAccType_Org.AccountType_Organisatie_GUID == myGuid)
        {
            //-- Create --
            myAccType_Org.AccountType_Organisatie_GUID = Guid.NewGuid();
            myAccType_Org.Organisatie_GUID = myOrg.Organisatie_GUID;

            csContext.Entry(myAccType_Org).State = EntityState.Added;
        }
        else
        {
            //-- Update --
            //-- Force MOdified state - even when unchanged --
            csContext.Entry(myAccType_Org).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        //myAccType_Org.AccountType = csContext.AccountTypes.Find(myAccType_Org.Accounttype_GUID);
    }

    //-- Explicitly handle Deletes --
    List<Guid> lGuids = myOrg.AccountType_Organisaties.Select(p => p.AccountType_Organisatie_GUID).ToList();
    csContext.AccountType_Organisaties.RemoveRange(csContext.AccountType_Organisaties.Where(p => p.Organisatie_GUID == myOrg.Organisatie_GUID).Where(q => !lGuids.Contains(q.AccountType_Organisatie_GUID)));


    csContext.Entry(myOrg).State = EntityState.Modified;
    csContext.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

1. I am explicitly deleting items from the context that are no longer present in the new model (posted back from edit page). Is this the best way to do this?
2. I am explicitly setting the State to modified for all (still) existing items, forcing an update - what is the best way to determine whether an update is necessary or not? Do I need to explicitly compare the new values of the item in the model to the item in the database?

Some help / guidelines on how to implement the above is appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to edit the question and simplify your code a bit. I'm having a hard time following it.

Comment: In general calling SaveChanges() will propagate all the changes done on objects to database so no explicit state change is necessary.

Comment: in the above code, csContext.SaveChanges only saves changes to the main entity (myOrg) and not to the related items (myOrg.AccountType_Organisaties).